# Заменить метод .live на .on

Tags: jquery

Как правильно заменить устаревший метод `.live` в строке:

```
$(".remove", $("#friends")).live("click", function(){
```

на метод `.on`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если элемент с ID "friends" статичен

```
$('#friends').on('click', '.remove', function() {

});
```

В ином случае

```
$(document).on('click', '#friends .remove', function() {

});
```